# Loop in a query to return the next 3 values from given variable

Tags: sql-server, loops

[REXTESTER Sample](http://rextester.com/SYN44789)

The query I have below returns the date 3 days later from the given variable `@incoming_date`. The catch is that the returned date cannot be a weekend or one of the ten federal holidays. For example, if today's date (11/16/2017) was given then it would return 11/20/2017. If the 20th was a federal holiday it would return the 21st. Or if 11/20 is given, 11/22nd is returned (today is inclusive). To determine if it is a holiday, I put the list of federal holidays in a table called `TEST_Holiday_dates` in a column called `Holiday_Date`.

```
declare @incoming_date date
declare @mydate date
declare @if_date_is_Holiday date
declare @if_weekend varchar(10)

set @incoming_date = '2018-01-11' --change this date to test
set @mydate = dateadd(day, 2, @incoming_date)

set @if_date_is_Holiday = (
                           select Holiday_Date
                           from TEST_Holiday_Dates
                           where Holiday_Date = @mydate
                          )
set @if_weekend = (
                   select convert(varchar(10), datename(dw, @mydate))
                   where
                   convert(varchar(10), datename(dw, @mydate)) = 'Saturday' 
                   or 
                   convert(varchar(10), datename(dw, @mydate)) = 'Sunday'
                  )

--select @mydate, @if_weekend, @if_date_is_Holiday

--Is a Holiday and not a weekend
if @if_date_is_Holiday is not null and @if_weekend is null
    begin
        if @if_weekend = 'Friday'
            begin
                if (select Holiday_Date from TEST_Holiday_Dates where Holiday_Date = dateadd(day, 3, @mydate)) is null
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 3, @mydate)
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 4, @mydate)
                    end
            end
        else 
            begin
                select dateadd(day, 1, @mydate)
            end
    end
--I think this is the same as "not a holiday and is a weekend logic"
--Is a Holiday and a weekend
else if @if_date_is_Holiday is not null and @if_weekend is not null
    begin
        if @if_weekend = 'Saturday'
            begin
                if (select Holiday_Date from TEST_Holiday_Dates where Holiday_Date = dateadd(day, 2, @mydate)) is null
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 2, @mydate)
                    end
                else
                    begin 
                        select dateadd(day, 3, @mydate)
                    end
            end
        else if @if_weekend = 'Sunday'
            begin
                if (select Holiday_Date from TEST_Holiday_Dates where Holiday_Date = dateadd(day, 1, @mydate)) is null 
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 1, @mydate)
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 2, @mydate)
                    end
            end
    end
--Is not a Holiday and not a weekend
else if @if_date_is_Holiday is null and @if_weekend is null
    begin
        select @mydate
    end
--Is not a Holiday but is a weekend
else if @if_date_is_Holiday is null and @if_weekend is not null
    begin
            if @if_weekend = 'Saturday'
            begin
                if (select Holiday_Date from TEST_Holiday_Dates where Holiday_Date = dateadd(day, 2, @mydate)) is null
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 2, @mydate)
                    end
                else
                    begin 
                        select dateadd(day, 3, @mydate)
                    end
            end
        else if @if_weekend = 'Sunday'
            begin
                if (select Holiday_Date from TEST_Holiday_Dates where Holiday_Date = dateadd(day, 1, @mydate)) is null 
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 1, @mydate)
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        select dateadd(day, 2, @mydate)
                    end
            end
    end
```

The query works fine to return one value. But what if I wanted to return the next 3 dates? i.e. If today's date is given (11/16) it would return 11/20, 11/22 and 11/24 (again, dates are inclusive). I am using sql-server 2014. Thanks in advance.

Example:

If I do `set @incoming_date = '2017-11-16'`

It will return the date `2017-11-20`

Which is correct, but I would like to include the next 3 inclusive dates so it would return:

```
2017-11-20
2017-11-22
2017-11-24
```

Or if I do `set @incoming_date = '2017-11-21'`

It currently returns `2017-11-24` (which is correct because the 23rd is Thanksgiving)

What I would like it to return:

```
2017-11-24
2017-11-27
2017-11-29
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do here. Can you post some sample data and the desired output for a given set of parameters?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry about that. I've added a few examples. Hope that helps.

Comment: @SeanLange Added a rextester sample as well.

Comment: @Simon I feel as though you're over complicating the problem.  You've provided a solution which, supplied a date, returns the next non-holiday business day.  Is there a reason you can't make this a function or stored procedure and simply call it 3 times?  Once for the first date, a second time for the product of the first call, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the query you've provided in your question into a stored procedure or function. For example:

```
dbo.ProcedureThatReturnsNextBusinessDay(@BaseDate DateTime, @Result DATETIME OUTPUT)
```

Then call this for every date you'd like to retrieve.  In your question you stated you wanted the next 3 dates:

```
DECLARE @BaseDate DATETIME = '11/20/2017',
        @DateOne DATETIME,
        @DateTwo DATETIME,
        @DateThree DATETIME;

EXEC dbo.ProcedureThatReturnsNextBusinessDay @BaseDate, @DateOne OUTPUT
EXEC dbo.ProcedureThatReturnsNextBusinessDay @DateOne, @DateTwo OUTPUT
EXEC dbo.ProcedureThatReturnsNextBusinessDay @DateTwo , @DateThree OUTPUT
```

Now the three dates you wanted exist in variables `@DateOne`, `@DateTwo` and `@DateThree`.

Comment: Didn't think of doing it this way. Thanks, I ultimately created my query as a function and had a store procedure execute it three times.